# CoreAVC 3.0.1 can't register on Win8.1 64bit

Tags: dll, h.264

I installed CoreAVC 3.0.1 on my Windows 8.1 64bit, and want to use its decoder in MPC-HC. 32bit versions of CoreAVC and MPC-HC on Win8.1 64bit worked well. But when it turns to 64bit, MPC-HC can't find CoreAVC, and re-register CoreAVCDecoder64.ax fails with "A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed" error. I have already re-installed CoreAVC for many times. Can somebody help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since nobody ever seems to have answered this...CoreAVC is simply not supported under Windows 8/8.1/10. It has not been updated in quite some time and appears as though it will not be in the near future. Best bet is to try the CCCP for MPC-HC.
If you want to run HD video with CoreAVC, you'd better just go back to Windows 7.